# method to copy(not move) a file on ftp server to another folder

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have a ftp server with a master folder(/master) and site folders 1-10 (/site001, /site002 etc) and need a way to copy, not move, files from the master into the site folders.

Best solution I can find via web searches is to copy the file locally, then upload to each of the folders. Given the files I'm working with are 100's of mb in size, it would be slow and inefficient to do this, esp when working with a file all 10 sites are to get.

My environment is two servers. A webserver (win server 2003) running the gui/web app, and then the FTP server. The FTP server is on a different network than the webserver. I'm using VS2010 and coding in VB .Net.

Comment: It's not possible, the FTP protocol doesn't support this. Using a programming language doesn't help since you still need to conform to FTP protocol.

Comment: As @EkoostikMartin alludes to, no client I've ever heard of supports copying to/from the same server, even if (per the RFC) it might technically be possible. Are you able to have something run on the ftp server itself? That would at least be more efficient than a download/reupload process.

Comment: Your going to have to download and the re-upload with another name. There is nothing in the generic FTP protocal but if you are working with a specific server/type, you might look to see if it has something specific to it.

Comment: That is a shame and makes no sense that over the years ftp has not been granted a simple copy command, nor can it be addressed via code. I was really hoping for some solution that at the very least would comprise of a creating a download command but point the destination back at the ftp server. Thanks for your replies.